# It's confusing when "that" is omitted

Tags: grammar

> "Arrow Publicity produced a campaign that is designed to appeal to audiences between the ages of 18 and 25."

My textbook says, even if omit the word 'that is', the meaning of this sentense does not change
however if this case, it could be interpreted that Arrow Publicity designed it, right?

*p.s) if any grammatical error of strange part in my question post, please point it out, thank you*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [move into the few buildings "still standing"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37634/move-into-the-few-buildings-still-standing)

Comment: Deletion of ***that is, which are***, etc. is called [*whiz-deletion.*](https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/p3tuyo/whiz_deletion/) So far as I know, this *never* changes the meaning. In your example, if Arrow Publicity "produced" something, the implication is they also *designed* it - but this is unaffected by whiz-deletion.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that 'whiz-deletion' is something that ESOL teachers and students talk about, but which ordinary native speakers have never heard of (like 'first' 'second' etc conditionals).

Comment: Since you ask, *if any grammatical error of strange part in my question post, please point it out, thank you* is very odd: I think you want to say *if there is any grammatical error or...* And *strange part* is grammatical but unidiomatic; you might say *if there is any grammatical error or anything else strange in my post, please point it out*.